# Add multiple columns to same file

Tags: shell, for-loop, append, addition, cut

My input file is input_file.csv with data as below:

```
Fname,Lname,Age,Gender,Address,Age,Gender,Address  
ABC,EFG,33,M,India,Age,Gender,Address  
PQR,XYZ,30,F,Canada,Age,Gender,Address
```

I want to add column 6 and column 3 dynamically to a new file output.csv. So I am trying below code:

```
final_col_count=8   -- total number of columns
inp_dummy_col_count=6   --- total number of varying columns

for ((i=3;i\<=final_col_count;i++))
do
testvar=`expr $i + $inp_dummy_col_count`  
cat input_file.csv | cut -d, -f$testvar \>\> output.csv  
cat input_file.csv | cut -d, -f$i \>\> output.csv
done
```

I am getting output as below:

```
Age
Age  
Age
Age
33
30
```

Whereas I want output as below:

```
Age,Age
Age,33  
Age,30
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $6 FS $3}' input_file.csv >output.csv` ?

Comment: `while IFS=, read _ _ c3 _ _ c6 _; do echo "$c6,$c3"; done <input_file.csv >output.csv` ?

Comment: These 2 alternatives in the comments are much better. Realize that your code `testvar=\`expr $i + $inp_dummy_col_count\`` starts a new process to run the `expr` for each record that is processed. For a small amount of data, this is tolerable, but if you get for larger files, you have developed a bad habit that is just slowing things down significantly. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cut` command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

final_col_count=8   # total number of columns
inp_dummy_col_count=6   # total number of varying columns

for ((i=3; i<=final_col_count; i++))
do
  testvar=$((i + inp_dummy_col_count))
  cut -d, -f$i,input_file.csv | paste -sd ',' - >> output.csv
  cut -d, -f$testvar,input_file.csv | paste -sd ',' - >> output.csv
done
```